# I'"Attempt to unlock ... which hasn't been locked" after installing node with nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I had this error when trying to use npm...
so I tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/3915033

1:
No way to uninstall it with apt-get, I had to do it myself with multiple

```
sudo rm -R
```

(couldn't uninstall npm neither)

2:

- Installed nvm in a folder owned by me
- group with me and the other user that need to use node
- permissions are rwxrwsr-x everywhere

which, I think, should allow everything to work for me and the other user of node

3:
did

```
nvm install 0.10
```

4:
no way to use npm !

tried:

```
npm -g install sails
```

which gave:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/edon/v0.10.36/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/edon/v0.10.36/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'sails' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.36
4 verbose cache add [ 'sails', null ]
5 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="sails" args=["sails",null]
6 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
6 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
6 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
6 verbose parsed url   host: null,
6 verbose parsed url   port: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
6 verbose parsed url   search: null,
6 verbose parsed url   query: null,
6 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'sails',
6 verbose parsed url   path: 'sails',
6 verbose parsed url   href: 'sails' }
7 silly lockFile e20e6cdc-sails sails
8 error Error: Attempt to unlock sails, which hasn't been locked
8 error     at unlock (/edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:44:11)
8 error     at cb (/edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:30:5)
8 error     at /edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:47:20
8 error     at /edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:22:20
8 error     at /edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:22:7
8 error     at Array.forEach (native)
8 error     at res (/edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:21:9)
8 error     at f (/edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:16:25)
8 error     at afterMkdir (/edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/get-stat.js:53:14)
8 error     at /edon/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
9 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
9 error including the npm and node versions, at:
9 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
10 error System Linux 2.6.32-042stab102.9
11 error command "/edon/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/edon/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "sails"
12 error cwd /edon
13 error node -v v0.10.36
14 error npm -v 1.4.28
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I suspect that maybe my removing of node and npm was not complete...

I've tried using nvm, npm, etc as root and no problem (it was problematic before i made all this)
I think we'll have to work on node as root but I'd prefer if it worked without it

(Sorry if my english is bad)